# Printing a variable inside a custom WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I would like to know how to print a variable inside a custom `WP_Query`.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' =>3,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

And I have a post type name value stored in a variable called `$post_type_name`.

However, when adding it to my code

```
<?php 
$post_type_name = get_sub_field('post_type_name'); 
$args = array (
  'post_type' => '$post_type_name',
  'posts_per_page' =>3, 
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
```

the code breaks. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotation, use flowing code. hope it will work

```
'post_type' => $post_type_name,
```

Comment: Excellent, it was exactly what's missing!